# Delphi XE4 iOS can't connect to PAServer

Tags: ios, delphi, connection, delphi-xe4

I have the PAServer running on my MacBook without password.

From my Windows/Delphi I then try setup the connection. I enter IP address and empty password. However, when testing the connection, I get error:

> TDBXError: Remote error:  Authentication manager rejected user
>   credientials. This may due to invalid combination of DS user name and
>   password

The question has been answered (Thanks!)

As a sidenote:
I am not sure how this could be closed as not a "real question"? :) Documentation, as I read it at least, did not state a password was required. Using a password solved the problem.

Comment: Try setting a password. Works for me, but I use a password.

Comment: That worked. Thanks Marcus. I am pretty sure help stated no password was okay, but I guess not. If you make an official answer, I will accept it as answer. :)

Comment: The first sentence in the original version of the question was irrelevant. However, this was otherwise perfectly acceptable as a question.

Comment: I have voted for reopening this question.

Comment: PAServer is not stable at this stage. It simply cannot be used. There are MANY reports about this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275202/paserver-cant-load-dyld-library  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259180/delphi-xe5-paserver-unauthorized-user  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713462/how-can-i-debug-my-dll-project-with-delphis-paserver  
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193480/delphi-xe4-ios-cant-connect-to-paserver  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115855/paserver-crashes-on-win64  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535892/delphi-mac-os-x

Comment: Just had the same issue. Restarting PAServer solved it.

Comment: Had this again after upgrading PAServer. Although credentials had not changed, "Test Connection" kept failing with this error. Inside PAServer, I generated a passfile (the `g` option) and used that. Then suddenly the connection _did_ succeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting a password. I have a password set on mine, and it works fine.

I don't recall anything that said you could use a blank (no) password. I would have done it if it worked.

Comment: I know this is too late to ask. But I am having hard time where to setup the password for PAServer? Can you help me please.. thanks.