# Delphi XE5 PAServer Unauthorized user

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a Windows 8.1 on a VirtualBox with Delphi XE5.

On my Mac OSX 10.9.1, I installed the package PAServer version 4.2.0.05 and executed with no password.

I've used previously in the PAServer XE4 version, so I know how it works, but tests with XE5 error occurs.

When I create an example app for iOS and deploy, I put the IP of my Mac and do a test connection, so I get the following message:

Remote Error: Unauthorized user, all server request are ignored.

- Ping from Windows to Mac is OK.
- I have no firewall enabled on Mac and Windows.
- I gave permission to all folders generated by PAServer on Mac.
- On Windows, I have a user with the same username of Mac.
- Using "sudo" to run the PAServer had no effect.

I have no more idea...

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Running_the_Platform_Assistant_on_a_Mac

Comment: have you tried everything from here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Installing_and_Running_the_Platform_Assistant_on_the_Target_Platform  ? If so, I believe you should contact EMB

Comment: I created a new VM in VirtualBox with Win 7 and it worked. I still dont know what the problem with Win 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

PAServer is not stable at this stage. There are MANY reports about this:

[PAServer can't load dyld: Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275202/paserver-cant-load-dyld-library)
[Delphi XE5 PAServer Unauthorized user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259180/delphi-xe5-paserver-unauthorized-user)
[How can i debug my DLL project with Delphi's PAServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713462/how-can-i-debug-my-dll-project-with-delphis-paserver)
 [Delphi XE4 iOS can't connect to PAServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193480/delphi-xe4-ios-cant-connect-to-paserver)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115855/paserver-crashes-on-win64
[Delphi Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535892/delphi-mac-os-x)

Solution: wait until they release something stable. (You will have to pay again, of course)