# Delphi Mac OS X

Tags: macos, delphi

I have problem with Delphi Mac OS X development. I get debug assertion failure error when I try to debug program. My application is just simple form where is few TLabel and TEdit component. Also there is two TImage components where is two images included. And there is also one TProgressBar component on my form. Connection between mac and my pc works ok. It tries to start application when I run it but it disappiers and Windows 7 and Delphi shows error debug assertion failure.

At first there was problem with deployment and my project file was corrupted so I created new project and then I added my old form to new project. After that compiling application works ok but now I get error message debug assertion failure.

I have Delphi XE5 and Windows 7 64-bit.
Mac computer is macbook pro.

Comment: It would be helpful to know Which assertion is failing.

Comment: Debug assertion failure "obj" in ..\win32src\rproxy.cpp at line 633

Comment: Does a empty FireMonkey (or a console) application work? Did you upgrade to latest OS X version and installed XE5 update 2?

Comment: No it doesnt work. I cant debug it. I have installed XE5 update 2.

Answer (score 2):

PAServer on OSX is a bit buggy and it sometimes crashes with these assertion failures. It's not your application that raises the assertion failure.

If PAServer crashes with an Assertion when trying to start your application, then I'd suggest the following:
1. Close Delphi and PAServer
2. Wait until both have completely shut down
3. Start Delphi and PAserver again
Sometimes this already solves the problem.

If this does not help, try starting your application from OSX from the Terminal and see what happens. Chances are you see an access violation or similar printed to the terminal window. If that is the case you might have a bug in the initialization part of a unit. PAServer likes to crash with an assertion failure if that happens. You'll have to debug the start-up process of your application using F7 and F8. You might be able to speed this up by setting breakpoints in the initialization of some units.

Comment: I can try that. If I want to copy my application release directly to mac computer. What files I have to copy to mac? I have two images on my form those two files I have to copy to mac but what other files I need to copy if I want to run my application release version? Is it easy to use TImagelist to include images to release file? I have two TImage components on my form.

Comment: You'd have to manually create a couple of files. So this is not so easy. Please teake a look at the scratch directory in OSX and see if your application is already there. Type s and hit enter in PAServer, then it will tell where you can find it. If you embed the images in the form, then you don't need to distribute them. Delphi doesn't include an ImageList that works on OSX.

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'a bit' buggy. In my case (Win64) is totally unusable.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Sebastian. PAServer is not stable at this stage. There are MANY reports about this:

[PAServer can't load dyld: Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275202/paserver-cant-load-dyld-library)
[Delphi XE5 PAServer Unauthorized user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259180/delphi-xe5-paserver-unauthorized-user)
[How can i debug my DLL project with Delphi's PAServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713462/how-can-i-debug-my-dll-project-with-delphis-paserver)
 [Delphi XE4 iOS can't connect to PAServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193480/delphi-xe4-ios-cant-connect-to-paserver)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115855/paserver-crashes-on-win64
[Delphi Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535892/delphi-mac-os-x)

Solution: wait until they release something stable. (You will have to pay again, of course)