# PAServer can't load dyld: Library

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe6

I am building a Desktop App for Windows and Mac. 
I am working on a Mac, with Delphi Rad Studio XE6 installed on my Parallel Windows 7. When Im running in Win32 everything runs ok, when I try to run in **OSX**, my **PAServer 14.0** says

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcgunwind.1.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/administrator/PAServer/scratch-dir/PC-Dionis/Project1.app/Contents/MacOS/Project1
  Reason: image not found
```

I read as much as possible in SO, I tried to manually copy the libcgunwind.1.0.dylib file into my scratch-dir, but as soon as I run the project, PAServer show the above message and the libcgunwind.1.0.dylib is deleted from the scratch-dir. I tried also launching it from the terminal, but it was the same. I read I can launch the paserver.command file,but I can't find it anywhere. Please some help!!

TIA

Comment: Did you follow the steps for deployment as described in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Deploying_Multi-Device_Applications), particularly the part about deploying an app on the Mac OS X platform?

Comment: Did you install PAServer both in Windows and on the Mac and register everything in the IDE? The built-in help describes extensively how to do that.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite! I followed them carefully and finally managed to run it on MAC OS X. I added as files there the dylib library and the .exe files I call using terminal. But I have another problem now. When I run it from delphi the terminal commands does not work properly. In the begging it said permission denied. I fixed that by using chmod 777. Than when I try to create a .txt file it says "Segmentation fault: 11"! And the command that tries to convert a image does not work at all. Anyway both of them work perfectly when i write them in terminal, without using delphi.

Comment: this are the lines I wrote to call this two terminal commands:_system(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('./dcmj2pnm '+ pathdcm + ' ' + pathbmp + ' +oj') ));
    
    _system(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('./dcmdump  '+ pathdcm +' > '+pathtxt) )) ;

Comment: "I have another problem now" means you need to start a new question and ask it there, not in the comments here.

Comment: thanks @KenWhite, I am a new member here

Comment: PAServer is way too buggy to be used at this stage. Embarcadero may fix it in Delphi XE8 but they will charge us again if we want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

PAServer is not stable at this stage. There are MANY reports about this:

[PAServer can't load dyld: Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275202/paserver-cant-load-dyld-library)
[Delphi XE5 PAServer Unauthorized user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259180/delphi-xe5-paserver-unauthorized-user)
[How can i debug my DLL project with Delphi's PAServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713462/how-can-i-debug-my-dll-project-with-delphis-paserver)
 [Delphi XE4 iOS can't connect to PAServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193480/delphi-xe4-ios-cant-connect-to-paserver)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115855/paserver-crashes-on-win64
[Delphi Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535892/delphi-mac-os-x)

Solution: wait until they release something stable. (You will have to pay again, of course)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Altar. I am no longer working on this project, the above problem I managed to solve by building from scratch the libraries needed for deploying an app on Max OS X.