# How can i debug my DLL project with Delphi's PAServer

Tags: delphi, dll, paserver

I Have a dll Project. I want to debug this Project with paserver on remote side. How can i pass my dll outpath dir on remote side and how can i pass my dll’s debug launcher application ?

For example my dll should be run on C:\MyApp\MyApp.DLL (On remote side)
And my debug launcher program should be run on C:\MyApp\MyDebugger.EXE (On remote side)

My Host application is Win32 VCL Application

Best Regards

Comment: Win32 or Win64? FMX or VCL in the host application?

Comment: Win32 VCL Application. Sorry about missing information

Comment: The [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Debugging_Multi-Device_Applications#Requirements_for_Multi-Device_Debugging_in_RAD_Studio) seem to not list Win32 as the list of supported debuggers, and it's not listed in the list of targets where you can run and debug (which lists Win64, Mac OS X, and iOS only) in the [PAServer docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/PAServer%2C_the_Platform_Assistant_Server_Application).. You can probably use the [old-style remote debugging](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Remote_Debugging_-_Old-Style_Procedures)

Comment: Win32 supported but i can convert win64.

Comment: PAServer is way too buggy and immature to be used at this stage. We need to way probably another 3-4 Delphi versions until we can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PAServer is not stable at this stage. It simply cannot be used. There are MANY reports about this:

[PAServer can't load dyld: Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275202/paserver-cant-load-dyld-library)
[Delphi XE5 PAServer Unauthorized user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259180/delphi-xe5-paserver-unauthorized-user)
[How can i debug my DLL project with Delphi's PAServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713462/how-can-i-debug-my-dll-project-with-delphis-paserver)
[Delphi XE4 iOS can't connect to PAServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193480/delphi-xe4-ios-cant-connect-to-paserver)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115855/paserver-crashes-on-win64
[Delphi Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535892/delphi-mac-os-x)
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-34061 (2021)

Solution: wait until they release something stable. (You will have to pay again, of course)

Answer (score 0):

follow solution as discussed here :  https://www.delphipraxis.net/204383-dll-unter-linux-deploy-prozess-2.html  (German only)