# Error on Creating of Connection Profile in RAD Studio after upgrading from Catalina OS version to Big Sur

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, macos-big-sur, paserver

I recently upgraded my Macbook Pro from Catalina version to Big Sur. Now, I am getting this error with my iOS Simulator. So I deleted the Connection Profile and created a new one. This time I am getting the following error:

`TDBXError: Remote error: Authentication manager rejected user credentials. This may be due to invalid combination of DS user name and password`

My PAServer by the way is running on my Mac terminal and used one of the IP provided. I am not using any password for my connection profile. My PAServer Version is 21.0 I am using 10.3 Community Version of RAD Studio.

There is a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17199259/13810710) to create a password but I don't know where to make a password in the PAServer.

Can someone assist me or ever encountered some issues with new Mac OS Big Sur version.

[image]

**UPDATE:** ERROR MESSAGE ON PASERVER WHEN I TRIED USING THE LOWER VERSION 20.0

```
OS/paserver ; exit;
Platform Assistant Server  Version 11.2.13.8
Copyright (c) 2009-2019 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.

Connection Profile password <press Enter for no password>: 

Starting Platform Assistant Server on port 64211

Type ? for available commands
>i
192.168.254.122
10.211.55.2
169.254.191.89
169.254.150.220
10.37.129.2
>Runtime error 231 at 0000000105F7605A
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...      56 completed.
```

[Process completed]

Comment: You say "PAServer Version is 21.0" Isn't that the wrong one for 10.3 Community Version? Shouldn't you be using the one for 20.0.

Comment: I've tried 20.0 but I am getting this error "EldConnClosedGracefully: Connection Closed Gracefully. I've checked my connection with Mac and it is all good.

Comment: The PAServer is giving an error message as well when I tried using lower version 20.0—please see update above.

Comment: Runtime error 231 is *Too many nested exceptions*.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree. This happens only when I upgraded Mac version to Big Sur. With little investigation, Parallels causes this error. There were times when my network (Mac to Parallel Windows) had some issues but already resolved that. The Parallels suggestions is not working also. I think I have to raise this issue with Parallels related to Big Sur update.